# What does -g flag mean in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am transcoding .mp4 files into hls format and I came into following line of command.
The command: `ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.mp4 -vf scale_npp=1280:720 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 8M -g 3 -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls output.m3u8`. I could not find the definition for `-g` flag. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

*-g E..V…. set the group of picture (GOP) size (from INT_MIN to INT_MAX) (default 12)*

And here is a full list of commands:

https://gist.github.com/tayvano/6e2d456a9897f55025e25035478a3a50

Some of it might be old as ffmpeg gets updated. Which version are you using?

Comment: I guess I am using the latest version 4.2.1. I built that ffmpeg by myself from source using nvidia drivers

Comment: what does group of picture mean btw?

Comment: Everything is a DuckDuckGo away :) https://esoterictek.blogspot.com/2017/04/understanding-ffmpegs-group-of-pictures.html

Answer (score 0):

Like Gaurav said, "-g" sets the group of picture size, and
I found the wikipedia article on Group of Pictures very helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures.

tl;dr frames are encoded as, literally, groups of pictures. In a single GOP, there are anchor frames (encoded independently from other frames), and predictive frames (encoded as a difference to other frames.)

I'm no expert on this but it seems like '-g' is just another option doing the space-quality trade and my guess (might be totally wrong) is the following:

Large group size -> less anchor frames -> smaller file -> lower quality